# How to loop through multiple pdf files using R libraries

Tags: r

I have a task to read in multiple pdf files and extract header and footer.

The below code helps me get header and footer from one file without any issue, but I want to do the same for multiple files and extract data. Please advise.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tm)

#Multiple files in a directory
files<- list.files(pattern='pdf$')

#File header and footer extraction
pdf_22 <- pdf_text("Test_List.pdf") %>% str_split("\n")

for (i in 1:35) {
    yy  <- pdf_22[[i]][-5:-24] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `lapply` :

```
library(pdftools)
files<- list.files(pattern='pdf$')

lapply(files, function(x) {
  lapply(strsplit(pdf_text(x), "\n"), `[`,  -5:-24)
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hey, that's amazing it extracts the lines I need but the number of lines are different in all pages, Is it possible to, just extract first page of every pdf file in the folder. So that my next task can be easy. If not I will accept this answer this works for now.

Comment: Do you mean like this ? `lapply(files, function(x) strsplit(pdf_text(x), "\n")[[1]][-5:-24]) -> result`

Comment: OMG, that's exactly what it is, Can we tell this code to ignore blank lines or empty lines in between.

Comment: Probably better to ask it as a new question since every question should be focussed on only one specific problem.